# Epson Stylus CX4300 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I have some problems with my Epson Stylus CX4300:

First - when I add the printer from `Settings-Devices` the specific driver for Stylus CX4300 doesn't exist in the data base, so I have to pick one between the CX4200 and CX4400.

Second - so I picked the CX4400, I noticed the printing process is slow, so I changed printing option and choose fast economy then start printing, and suddenly the printer shutdown, and when I start it again it won't print anything as if the printer is in stand-by.

Third - the scanner doesn't work at all.

Fourth - I try to get the driver of the CX4300 from Epson web site, and I didn't find any for Debian 64bit.